# how do I set servers for hadoop? (CDH)

Tags: hadoop, cloudera

I am running 3 instances using AWS EC2 (m1.small -- 20GB HDD & 1.7 GB RAM).

On the cluster, there will be hadoop, mapReduce, and several monitoring processes.

This is how I split :

### 1 Master server

- NameNode
- SecondaryNameNode
- JobTracker
- Activity Monitor
- Alert Publisher
- Event Server
- Host Monitor
- Service Monitor

### 2 Slave servers

- TaskTracker
- DataNode

Because of the server's spec, I think it is kind of burden for the master server to run those 8 jobs. How do I divide them? Should I make another server to allocate monitoring processes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having NameNode & SeondaryNameNode on same server does not serve any purpose.

With 1.7 GB ram /machine i don't think you can do much. You need more nodes or higher configuration. 8GB/ Node i think should be minimum.

You can assign some services to slave nodes also.

Comment: Yes, I agree. As a reference, CDH 5 VM requires 8 gigs or RAM

Comment: 8gb RAM for each node?
How many servers should I prepare for making the cluster work as minimum?
CDH recommends at least 3 data nodes, so How many I need is 3 hosts for three data nodes and 1 host for namenode, and 1 for secondarynamenode. 5 hosts as minimum, right?

Comment: Your secondary name node could reside with one of your datanodes. Are you going to use this as production? If not you could set the replication factor to 2 and use only 2 data nodes. Slightly unstable but will serve development purpose.